# How to use reflection to find certain classes in an assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have a .Net assembly loaded and I want to use reflection to find the classes (types) decorated with some attribute, eg

```
[MyClassAttribute]
public SomeClass
{
}
```

how do I do it in C#? I have got as far as

```
Assembly assy = Assembly.Load(assyPath);
var classesInAssy = assy.GetTypes();
```

but thereafter I'm stumped. I now know I have to use the CustomAttibutes collection on the type, but I'm using VS2013 Pro (which includes unit testing), and the attribute in question isn't one of mine but the MS TestClass attribute. However I can't seem to reference the assembly it is defined in (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll) even though the dll is listed in the Add References dialog in VS2013. Am I missing something?

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Jon Skeet's answer is to use `GetCustomAttributes`:

```
Type[] classesWithAttr = assy.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyClassAttribute), false).Length > 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Well dang, right after being marked as duplicate. Oops.

Comment: Thanks, but please see my edited question. Do I have a some VS2013 problem?

Comment: @NeilHaughton I think that your problem with referencing a unit test attribute should be another question entirely. It seems separate from this one.

Comment: What I mean is that I can't compile .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute)....) unless I reference the dll in which it is defined, and VS2013 won't let me add it to the project.

Comment: Ok, I shall raise another question if it can't be answered here.

Comment: @NeilHaughton I understood what you meant the first time. I think that should be another question about referencing that unit test class when VS2013 won't let you.

Comment: No worries, done. Comments are clearly crossing.